# Delete query won't run

Tags: query, wpdb

This is the set up:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="delete_app_id" id="delete_app_id" value='<?php 
        echo $adoptee->app_id; ?>' />
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" />
</form>
<?php

if ( isset( $_POST['delete'] ) ) {
    $delete_id=$_POST['delete_app_id'];
    $adoptees_delete=$wpdb->query( "DELETE 
        FROM $wpdb->rc_vol_adopt_apps 
        WHERE app_id ='$delete_id'" );
    if ( $adoptees_delete ) {
        echo 'Record Deleted';
    } else{
        echo 'Have a ham sandwich - cause this FAILED';
    }
}
```

And it won't run!  It is picking up the `delete_app_id` and the `delete` from the post submit, but nothing happens after that. It's like it can't see the `if isset` statement. What am I missing?

Comment: Post [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). I suspect that there is information missing from this question. Please think hard about whether you have forgotten to mention something.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why `$_POST['delete']` should not be set assuming there are no page redirects involved. I can't tell from your code if that is the case, but it superficially appears not to be. I do see other potential problems.

1. You are setting your form `action` to an empty string. While that
   does sometimes work, it can sometimes also cause trouble. Set that
   explicitly. I believe that an empty `action` is also invalid, at
   least in HTML 5 and I think HTML 4 also.
2. Depending on context you may need `global $wpdb;` before you can use
   `$wpdb`. It is safer just to include that part than to assume it is
   available.
3. [If `app_id` is a numeric column type you _might be causing yourself
   trouble by quoting `$delete_id`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8022464/1735890)
4. You are passing unvalidated/unsanitized user data into the database.
   That is very dangerous. As is, a user could delete rows from your
   table with very little effort. `POST` is not safe. At the very, very
   least use `$wpdb->prepare`:

   ```
   $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM $wpdb->rc_vol_adopt_apps WHERE app_id = %d",$delete_id));
   ```

   That said, I usually [run my own checks to make sure the data is what it should be](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation).
5. `$wpdb->query` can return both `0`, no rows effected, and `false`,
   query failed. PHP will interpret `0` as `false` so you shoudlb e
   checking the output with `if (false !== $adoptees_delete)` and not
   with the simple, and potentially `notice` throwing, check you've
   got.
6. It is better to process the `POST` before the form then `unset` the
   `POST` data or, much better, redirect the request back to itself.
   Otehrwise, you can get problems with multiple submissions of the
   form.

Comment: thanks for the input but doesn't do a thing to answer my question:-/

Comment: I pasted your form into a page and hit the submit ("delete") button. `isset($_POST['delete'])` returns `true`. The problem is not what you think it is-- that "it can't see the if isset statement". The problem is 1) not what you think it is or 2) you've left out critical information. Those are the problems that I do see. I'd fix those issues before deciding those issues aren't the problem.

Comment: Thanks for checking into it and giving me a direction.  And already made the changes suggested - no difference...  it is interesting when I take the isset post 'delete' out and make it blank - it returns - record deleted without deleting anything.  will keep trying to pin it down.  Certainly a 'newbie' at this business - learning more every day;-)

Comment: Found the answer.  The logic of the delete statement was running in the foreach.  I took that out and placed it above and all worked perfectly.  Learn something new everyday!

Comment: There is no `foreach` in the code you posted.

Answer (score -1):

first declare $wpdb as global.
second you need to debug the query in $wpdb using print_r().
also try to copy that query to run it into mysql directly.